# How to check who deleted a table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, logging

I have a MySQL database that is accessed by many users.
Today, I noticed that suddenly some of the tables disappeared, probably someone deleted them.

Is there a possibility to check which user did that? A log or something? Is this stored somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your user have admin rights?

Comment: Yes, all the user have admin rights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way, in my opinion, is to check the MySQL server Logs, read the documentation about statements, which changes the data [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html).

If you have access to the file system of your MySQL server this would not be hard, just locate where is the log. By default, the server writes files for all enabled logs in the data directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot bodi0, yes, I have the access to the server. I will try to find the logs.

Comment: Did you ever access to the log on Google Cloud SQL Instance?